# How to save pthread_t id to an array

Tags: c, pthreads

How can i save the id of p_thread to an array?

```
int i;
pthread_t t[N];
float arrayId[N];


for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, f, (void *) &i);
    printf("creato il thread id=%lu\n", t[i]);
    arrayId[i] = t[i];
    printf("a[%d]=%f\n", i, arrayId[i]);
}
```

I can print it, but i'm not able to save...

I'll have to sort this array and then i'll have to execute first all the thread ordered by id

Comment: What do you mean with `save`? since `t` already contains each thread id, it is 'saved' so why would you need another array? And even if you would, it does not make sense to use float for it.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759794/how-to-print-pthread-t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All threads will receive the same value for `i` because you are passing it by value (the same address).
This should fix it:

```
int i;
pthread_t t[N];
float arrayId[N];

int indexes[N];

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    indexes[i] = i;
    pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, f, (void *) &indexes[i]);
    printf("creato il thread id=%lu\n", t[i]);
    arrayId[i] = t[i];
    printf("a[%d]=%f\n", i, arrayId[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
I'll have to sort this array and then i'll have to execute first all the thread 
ordered by id
```

`pthread_create` already executes a thread as man states:

```
The  pthread_create() function starts a new thread in the calling process.
```

So your loop already starts N threads. Also you can't specify thread ids, they are returned when threads are created.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save the array. You simply define a function, `f`, that you wish to operate on these numbers, and then, as you have done in your `pthread_create()`, have that function, `f`, as an input.

Each time `pthread_create()` is called the function, `f`, will be executed.