# Why and in what sense is pthread_t an opaque type?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Posts here on SO suggest that `pthread_t` is an opaque type, not a number, certainly not a thread index, that you shouldn't directly compare `pthread_t`'s, etc. etc.

Questions:

1. Why? Is there really the intent to support systems with no numeric IDs for threads? When the `pthread_t` implementation is simply

   ```
   typedef unsigned long int pthread_t;
   ```

   ?
2. How? There's a comment before the above line, so it's actually

   ```
   /* Thread identifiers. The structure of the attribute type is not
      exposed on purpose.  */
   typedef unsigned long int pthread_t;
   ```

   in `pthreadtypes.h` what does that mean? What attribute type? Isn't this an index into some global table of threads?

Comment: Would that not depend on the underlying OS API?  Nobody outside of an OS kernel wants to keep a global table of threads - it would not be reliable.

Comment: @MartinJames: If that's the reason pthreads is like that, make your comment an answer... but - I would think that either the index is into the OS' table of threads, or into the library's table of threads when the OS doesn't expose one/have one.

Comment: FYI on practical real-world implementations it's actually a pointer, not an integer/index. Sometimes said pointer is stuffed into an integer type like `unsigned long` (this assumes ILP32 or LP64 model) for legacy compatibility reasons but the content is actually an address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there really the intent to support systems with no numeric IDs for threads?

There are different types that could serve as numeric thread identifier. For example, on systems with limited resources an 8-bit thread identifier could be used instead of `unsigned long`.

> The structure of the attribute type is not exposed on purpose.

The comment is *not* for `pthread_t` definition, but for the `pthread_attr_t` definition one line below:

```
typedef union
{
  char __size[__SIZEOF_PTHREAD_ATTR_T];
  long int __align;
} pthread_attr_t;
```

The comment states that `char __size[__SIZEOF_PTHREAD_ATTR_T]` is used in order to hide the content of the actual `struct`.

> Isn't [`pthread_t`] an index into some global table of threads?

It does not have to be. The fact that the actual type is hidden allows an implementer to use any type that he wishes, including a pointer or a `struct`. Using a `struct` lets the implementer avoid using a global table of threads in the code of his library (OS would probably keep such table, though).

Comment: Well, the actual type is not really hidden, but, ok.

Answer (score 6):

The POSIX standard allows `pthread_t` to be something more complex (such as a structure). [See this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759794/how-to-print-pthread-t), especially the answer by @james-mcnellis. Money quote:

> IEEE Std 1003.1-2001/Cor 2-2004, item XBD/TC2/D6/26 is applied, adding
>   pthread_t to the list of types that are not required to be arithmetic
>   types, thus allowing pthread_t to be defined as a structure.

**UPDATE**: Here are a few examples of more complex `pthread_t` definitions:

- https://github.com/JoakimSoderberg/pthreads-win32/blob/master/pthread.h
- http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/project/pthreads/include/pthread.h
- http://svn.gna.org/svn/xenomai/trunk/include/posix/pthread.h

And here is an ancient (2007) justification of the `pthread_t` structure used in the pthreads library for Win32: https://sourceware.org/ml/pthreads-win32/2007/msg00056.html