# pthread doesn't let you get the tid?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, glibc

In Linux, the tid is retrieved with a syscall: `gettid()`.

The [pthread](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/nptl/descr.h.html#pthread) object stores the tid in struct pthread:

```
struct pthread {
...

  /* This descriptor's link on the `stack_used' or `__stack_user' list.  */
  list_t list;

  /* Thread ID - which is also a 'is this thread descriptor (and
     therefore stack) used' flag.  */
  pid_t tid;

  /* Ununsed.  */
  pid_t pid_ununsed;
...
};
```

I believe this structure is stored at the base of the stack? Anyway, every pthread has access to it. For instance, in the [pthread_create](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/nptl/pthread_create.c.html#695) implementation, it grabs the struct pthread:

```
struct pthread *self = THREAD_SELF;
```

So my question is: why is there no `pthread_gettid_np()` call? Perhaps `gettid()` is so fast somehow it's negligible? Or maybe the call exists and I just can't find it anywhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why and in what sense is pthread\_t an opaque type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285562/why-and-in-what-sense-is-pthread-t-an-opaque-type)

Comment: This is something that the glibc team has been arguing about internally for years.  If you could extract the tid from a pthread_t you could do things with it that break the library's assumptions. On the other hand there are several valid use cases. So far no consensus and therefore no action.

Comment: I don't think so... I'm asking about `tid`s? As far as I understand pthread_t id's are a purely userspace contrivance for internal datastructures.

Comment: I'm assuming the 'assumptions' you're referring to are some break from a 1-1 relationship between pthread_t and tid. Perhaps you can hack a pthread to have multiple stacks somehow (multiple tids)? I don't know how the other way around would be possible - 1 pthread_t mapping to 2 tids.

Comment: @chub500 It's more complicated than that. I don't remember what the problem was well enough to explain and I don't have time today to dig up any of the threads on the mailing list about it. Sorry.

Comment: Well thank you for the pointer above anyway! A quick google lead me to this thread (no pun intended): https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6399 - incredibly informative.