# Why does pthread_join not take a thread pointer?

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads

Pretty self explanatory question. For example, the header for pthread_create shows it takes a pointer to a thread:

```
int WINPTHREAD_API pthread_create(pthread_t *th, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(* func)(void *), void *arg);
```

OK, makes sense, you allocate a pthread in memory then pass a pointer to pthread_create so it gets initialized... but now looking at the header for pthread_join:

```
int WINPTHREAD_API pthread_join(pthread_t t, void **res);
```

It takes a copy of the pthread_t. I just don't get why it doesn't take a pointer to that already existing thread, rather than copying it and passing it over; it seems like if anything, doing so would cause more problems and more memory use. Am I missing something? I read the manpage, it doesn't seem to offer a reason to this.

Comment: pthread_t is already an id, almost the same as a pointer. Passing it by pointer would be redundant, unless you intend to modify it.

Comment: `pthread_create` has to change the value, therefore it needs it as a pointer. `pthread_join` only needs the value, so pass by value is fine.

Comment: @MarcGlisse crap, I was under the impression pthread_t was a struct, I didn't realize it was just an ID...

on that note, any particular reason pthread_create doesn't just return a pthread_t if it's just an ID?

Comment: See this discussion about the `pthread_t` type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285562/why-and-in-what-sense-is-pthread-t-an-opaque-type

Comment: @MarcGlisse _"...doesn't just return a pthread_t..."_ -  `pthread_create` is a C interface it need to be able to return an error code, it can't throw an exception.

Comment: @TheCornInspector, `pthread_t` could be a struct.  It could also be a pointer or an integer.  To the extent that Marc is asserting that it is similar *in form* to a pointer, his claim is not supported by the specifications.  But he is absolutely correct that objects of that type serve the *role* of an ID.  POSIX has defined the pthreads interfaces in a way that affords implementations considerable flexibility for how they define `pthread_t`, among other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It takes a copy of the `pthread_t`.

Yes.

> I just don't get why it doesn't take
> a pointer to that already existing thread,

`pthread_t` is a thread *identifier*.  The specs consistently refer to it that way.  Copying it does not duplicate the thread itself, nor consume more memory than one `pthread_t` occupies.

> rather than copying it and
> passing it over; it seems like if anything, doing so would cause more
> problems and more memory use.

It does not necessarily cause more memory use, as a `pthread_t` is not necessarily larger than a pointer.  It might *be* a pointer, or an integer.  Even if it is a structure, however, there is no reason to think that it so large that passing it by value presents a significant problem, because the specifics are under control of the pthreads implementation.  Why would implementers shoot themselves in the foot that way?  Note well that passing a structure by value is not *inherently* less efficient than passing a pointer.

As for problems other than excessive memory use, you would have to be more specific, but I don't see any issues inherent in accessing a copy of a thread identifier directly *vs*. accessing a common identifier object indirectly, for the purposes of those functions that accept a `pthread_t` by value.

> Am I missing something?

I suspect that your concerns are tied up in a misunderstanding of type `pthread_t` as somehow carrying data supporting thread operation as opposed to simply identifying a thread.

You may also be supposing that pthreads is a library, with a particular implementation, whereas in fact, it is first and foremost a *specification*, designed to afford multiple implementations.  This is part of the reason for defining abstract data type `pthread_t` instead of specifying `int` or `struct something *` -- implementations can choose what actual type to use.

Perhaps you are also focusing too closely on the API functions.  Even if in some particular implementation, passing a `pthread_t` by value to, say, `pthread_join()` were less efficient than passing a pointer to one, how much of an impact do you suppose that would actually have?  `pthread_join()` is called infrequently, and only in cases where the caller is prepared to block.  What does it matter if argument passing consumes a few more nanoseconds than it might otherwise do?

> I read the
> manpage, it doesn't seem to offer a reason to this.

Few manual pages provide rationale for function design, but I think the most likely explanation is essentially that form follows function.  Those functions that receive a `pthread_t` by value do so because they do not need or want to modify the caller's value. The functions' designs reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

A `pthread_t` is a small object which identifies a thread. It could be a pointer, integer or perhaps a tiny structure. The `pthread_t` isn't actually the thread itself any more than a `HWND` object in Win32 is the window itself.

The `pthread_create` function returns this identifier via a pointer pointer because it already returns a value of type `int` for error indication. Other functions take `pthread_t` by value.

For instance, to compare whether two `pthread_t` objects refer to the same thread, you should use `pthread_equal`, which takes two `pthread_t` parameters. It's possible that all this function does is compare the two values using `==`, but doing that directly wouldn't be as portable. It won't even compile if `pthread_t` happens to be a small structure.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note is that pthread is a C API. Unlike C++ which has constructors, copying a C variable is guaranteed to be reasonably inexpensive. The worst case would be a type that is a large structure but even then, it's only a memcpy. This is different than C++ where a copy can invoke an arbitrarily expensive constructor.